# Access directive from html element in code

Tags: angular

Is there a way to retrieve a custom @directive from an HTMLElement by code?

e.g. let's say that I have declared the following directive

`@Directive({selector: '[appCustomDirective]'})
export class MyCustomDirective {
    public MyVariable: string;
}`

that is attached to a button:

`<button appCustomDirective>My button<button>`

if I have the button as an HTMLElement variable, Is there a way to:

- check whether it has the appCustomDirective attached?
- retrieve the instance of the directive?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the directive via the injector on the element you've returned.

The component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-custom-component',
  template: `
    <button id="with-directive" appMyCustomDirective>Click Me</button>
    <button id="without-directive">Click Me Too</button>
  `
})
export class MyCustomComponent {
}
```

The directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyCustomDirective]'
})
export class MyCustomDirective {
  public myVariable = 'hello there!';
}
```

The test:

```
describe('MyCustomComponent', () => {
 let component: MyCustomComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyCustomComponent>;

 beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [
       MyCustomComponent,
       MyCustomDirective
     ]
   })
     .compileComponents();
 }));

 beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyCustomComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 it('displays a button with the directive', () => {
   const buttonWithDirective = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#with-directive'));
   const directiveInstance: MyCustomDirective = buttonWithDirective.injector.get(MyCustomDirective);
   expect(directiveInstance.myVariable).toBe('hello there!');

   const buttonWithoutDirective = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#without-directive'));
   //danger!! this will throw an exception because there is no directive
   //const directiveInstance: MyCustomDirective = buttonWithDirective.injector.get(MyCustomDirective);
 });
});
```

Comment: Your answer is clear and very well documented. I am still missing a way to get the injector of an HTMLComponent though. (In your case, you are accessing the injector of a DebugElement). Any help with that?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what is it you're trying to accomplish? Maybe provide a more specific example? Are you testing something? HTMLElement isn't an Angular interface, so an "HTMLElement" variable won't have an "injector" prop to get things the dependency injector provides.